# Get Header value of response in asp.net page with dashes

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers

I know this is easy but I cant get this to work.  I have a response header below.

```
X-Exposure-Server:EastUS2
```

I am spitting it out like this

```
<span>@Response.Headers["X-Exposure-Server"]</span>
```

However, it's blank.  Why?

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Exposure-Server: EastUS2
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Date: Tue, 19 Apr 2016 04:39:53 GMT
Content-Length: 11017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I got this to work was set this in the BeginRequest, EndRequest was after the page was rendered.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("X-Exposure-Server", Config.Settings.ServerRegion);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding custom header to response, then it is available.Just check the values of Response.Headers in quick watch.Tried your scenario.I added my response header Response.AddHeader("myheader", "myheadervalue"); and tried to consume it in view like - @Response.Headers["myheader"],it displayed the value.Only the headers added by mvc are displayed.

Comment: Is this X-Exposure-Server response header added by default by IIS?There are only standard response headers that can return(default) and this is not one of them.chk this link -msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537417(v=vs.85).aspx ; IIS can return 4response headers which starts with X-* ,but what you are getting is not one of these.so how is the IIS returning your mentioned header.

Comment: Its not added by default, I ADDED IT.

Comment: If you add any custom headers, you can read as explained above.How are you adding this header?via code or through IIS settings?

Comment: Through IIS of course.  I added this as a custom header so I know where the request comes from via the Server as we are load balancing.  However, the code above says its empty???

Comment: The key is not present in the Response.Headers.Added one solution.pls check it

Comment: I dont believe I can grab headers set in IIS.  I tried on my local and its not found as a Key.

Comment: Did you try the above answer of adding module?

Answer (score 1):

The key is accessible only if its set through code.So check this approach
create a class which inherits IHttpModule and implement it.

```
public class HTTPHeaderModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(context_EndRequest);
    }

    void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        response.AddHeader("X-Exposure-Server","EastUS2e");
        //You can read this(EastUS2e) value from web.config
    }
}
```

Now add a line in web.config in the HttpModule section:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="HTTPHeaderModule" , type="HTTPHeaderModule" />
 </httpModules>
```

MSDN ref:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858%28VS.71%29.aspx